# Stored procedure only runs once

Tags: c#, ado.net, webapi

I have a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextNumber
    @NextNumber int OUT
AS
    UPDATE SystemSettings 
    SET REGISTRY_NUMBER = REGISTRY_NUMBER + 1  
    WHERE ID = 1;

    SELECT @NextRegistryNumber = REGISTRY_NUMBER
    FROM SystemSettings
    WHERE ID = 1;
  
    SELECT 'NextNumber' = @NextRegistryNumber;
```

I call this from a C# API method:

```
public int GetNextRegistryNumberFC()
{
    string procedure = "GetNextNumber";
        
    // Create ADO.NET objects.
    // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con);

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[<ConnectionString>].ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con))

    try
    {
        // Configure command and add input parameters.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the output parameter.               
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NextNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                

        // Execute the command.
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        NextRegistryNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NextNumber"].Value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

    return NextRegistryNumber;
}
```

This works the first time I run it. After that it just return the same number each time instead of incrementing it. I am not sure what I happening. If I run the stored procedure by it self it works each time. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: SQL Server already has a SEQUENCE object. There's no reason for this stored procedure. The try/catch/finally block isn't needed either - `using` ensures the connections will be closed even in cases where `finally` wouldn't execute. Rethrowing a caught exception without even logging it is the same as not catching at all

Comment: The stored procedure isn't working properly either. It will fail if it's called by multiple requests at the same time. Both executions will increase the counter, then both will return the *same* value. You should [create a sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) eg with `CREATE SEQUENCE RegistryNumbers;` and then execute `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR RegistryNumbers; `. You don't need a stored procedure for this, `ExecuteScalar` will execute the query and return the new value

Comment: Thanks so much, the sequence object works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stored procedure will produce unexpected results if it's called by two or more connections at the same time. Both executions will increment the field then both return the same value. Even if this was fixed, the update query creates a hotspot in a single row, with concurrent requests blocking while they wait for each other to update that row.

To avoid this, SQL Server (and other databases) have [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) objects that can be incremented atomically with minimal locking :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Registration_Numbers START WITH 1;
```

The [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function will increment a sequence and return the new value :

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Registration_Numbers;
```

This query is so short it doesn't need a stored procedure :

```
var sql="SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Registration_Numbers;";
using(var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con))
{
    var new_id=(long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return new_id;
}
```

There's no need for `try/catch` here. A `using` block ensures the connection and command objects will be disposed even if an exception occurs. `using` works even in cases where `finally` wouldn't be called.

Rethrowing isn't needed either. The following `catch` block is no different than no `catch` at all.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Such a block would make sense if the exception was processed, eg logged.

**Atomic update and read**

If using a table is absolutely necessary (why?), the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause can be used to return the new value right from the UPDATE command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextNumber
AS
    UPDATE SystemSettings 
    SET REGISTRY_NUMBER = REGISTRY_NUMBER + 1  
    OUTPUT inserted.REGISTRY_NUMBER
    WHERE ID = 1;
```

The same code can be used to call the stored procedure. Only the the `CommandType` needs to change

```
var proc_name=" dbo.GetNextNumber";
using(var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(proc_name,con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var new_id=(long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return new_id;
}
```

Comment: Note also that `SEQUENCE` defaults to `bigint`/`long` but will also accept `tinyint` `int` `smallint` and `decimal`

Comment: This SEQUENCE object works so well. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: The Unexpected result can be resolved by wrapping it in a Transaction to make it atomic which is basically doing the same thing mentioned here.
If you're not using transitions in stored procedures or from your code already, that are multiuse like this, you need to learn that next.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo?

```
SELECT 'NextNumber' = @NextRegistryNumber;
```

This would output a table with a column called 'NextNumber' with the value in @NextRegistryNumber ie: you've done a column alias.

It should be:

```
SELECT @NextNumber = @NextRegistryNumber;
```

OR

```
SET @NextNumber = @NextRegistryNumber;
```

Comment: I changed some of the variables for the example. I think this was the problem here.